# How to show and block incoming UDP packets

Tags: c#, winforms, udp, packet-capture, udpclient

How to show and block ip UDP incoming in c# WinForms. 
Show ip and incoming packet in label like Anti DDOS Guardian

Comment: Why not use Windows inbuilt, or third party, firewall?

Comment: Can you please specify what you're trying to do? Do you want to check all incoming packets on a specific socket or what else?

Comment: I want to check and block UDP Flood DDOS

Comment: Ok, but you want to achieve this in an existing WinForm application or create a new ad hoc application?

Comment: Create new :) ,i want begin from new project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a similar application some years ago using [WinpkFilter](http://www.ntkernel.com/?Products:Development_Toolkits:Windows_Packet_Filter_Kit). I don't know if there is something better, but this gives you all that need to read all packets passing on network interface. Once you read the packets, you can check protocol type and make all operation you need to prevent DDOS.

You have to install the WinpkFilter driver and link the ndisapi.dll library, I suggest you to give it a try and see if this can help you.